# Download a bibtex from GitHub into R

Tags: r, github, bibtex

I have a BibTex file stored in GitHub, here:

https://raw.github.com/zoometh/C14/master/neonet/references_france.bib

The file shows bibliographical references like that:

```
@article{Binder18,
  title={Modelling the earliest north-western dispersal of Mediterranean Impressed Wares: new dates and Bayesian chronological model.},
  author={Binder, Didier and Lanos, Philippe and Angeli, Lucia and Gomart, Louise and Guilaine, Jean and Manen, Claire and Maggi, Roberto and Muntoni, Italo M and Panelli, Chiara and Radi, Giovanna and others},
  journal={Documenta praehistorica.},
  volume={44},
  pages={54--77},
  year={2018},
  publisher={University of Ljubljana Department of Archaeology}
}

@inproceedings{Briois09,
  title={L'abri de Buholoup: de l'{\'E}pipal{\'e}olithique au N{\'e}olithique ancien dans le piedmont central des Pyr{\'e}n{\'e}es},
  author={Briois, Fran{\c{c}}ois and Vaquer, Jean},
  booktitle={De M{\'e}diterran{\'e}e et d'ailleurs...: m{\'e}langes offerts {\`a} Jean Guilaine},
  pages={141--150},
  year={2009}
}
...
```

I want to download it into R but the following code not working:

```
library(bibtex)
bib <- read.bib('https://raw.github.com/zoometh/C14/master/neonet/references_france.bib')

# Error: unable to open file to read
```

... But, it works when I read it from a local folder.

How can I download a `.bib` from GitHub into R/RStudio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `read.bib` works remotely so you could download the file first.

```
library(utils)
URL <- "https://raw.github.com/zoometh/C14/master/neonet/references_france.bib"
download.file(url = URL, destfile=basename(URL))
    
library(bibtex)
bib <- read.bib(basename(URL))
    
head(bib,1)
# Binder D, Lanos P, Angeli L, Gomart L, Guilaine J, Manen C, Maggi R, Muntoni IM, Panelli C, Radi
# G, others (2018). “Modelling the earliest north-western dispersal of Mediterranean Impressed
# Wares: new dates and Bayesian chronological model.” _Documenta praehistorica._, *44*, 54-77.
```